# Unprocessable Entity: Using jquery Ajax delete call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've been facing issue of `Unprocessable Entity`. I am working on ruby on rails. When I send and ajax call to server my ajax code is.

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'repository/destroyitems',
        data:selected,
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function(result) {
    // Do something with the result
    debugger;
   }
```

});

In controller I have simple actions

Comment: Remove `debugger` from your ajax call . And update your Question with Development log.

Comment: I think that debugger is in call back method so it will not matter :)

Comment: will you tell us what `selected` variable is ?

Answer (score 0):

Try out with this ....

```
   $("#button").click(function(event){ 
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'))},
            url:  "repository/destroyitems" + selected,
            data: {"_method":"delete"},
            success: function(){
               ... # Your Logic
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
```

Would work !!!

Comment: 'Selected' word is array of id

Comment: @user3789726: Fine... Just try with this, it would solved your problem.

Comment: this is error is related to xhr request header configuration

Comment: @user3789726: Yes you are right, meanwhile Just update your `controller code` So that I can help you to sort out the issue.

Comment: i am able to post my ajax request but its gives 404 error when i  pass 'selected' element with it, if i d'not pass parameters it works fine

Comment: @user3789726: user could use query parameter to make work .

Comment: `$.ajax({
            type: "DELETE",
            url:  'repository/destroyitems?id='+selected,
            data: selected,
            success: function(response){
           debugger;
             //  ... Your Logic
            }
        }); `dfgfdg`
I have tried query parameter still 404 error. thanks for your help. still getting 404 error